# How can I iterate correct inside a for in loop inside the Array.prototype.replace method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object, replace

I'm converting a string with help of regex and replace method. The script check if an abbreviation exist in the abbreviations array IF the word is less then three characters long. This is done in the callback inside the [`String.prototype.replace() method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

I believe the issue is inside the [`for...in statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

I get this string: `"BLABLABLALBLA COOL DOG"`, but it should return `"BLABLABLALBLA CAT COOL DOG CAT"` if the for in method should be working correct...

```js
    const abbreviations = [
      { abbreviation: "d", expansion: "dog" },
      { abbreviation: "c", expansion: "cat" },
      { abbreviation: "h", expansion: "horse" }
    ];
    
    const testStringOriginal = "      blablablalbla,  / c  coOL @ d p  233c    ";
    
    const filterPattern1 = /[^a-zA-Z]+/g; // find all non English alphabetic characters.
    const filterPattern2 = /\b[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\b/g; // find words that are less then three characters long.
    const filterPattern3 = /\s\s+/g; // find multiple whitespace, tabs, newlines, etc.
    
    const filteredString = testStringOriginal
      .replace(filterPattern1, " ")
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter
      .replace(filterPattern2, match => {
        console.log("typeof: ", typeof match);
        for (abbreviation in abbreviations) {
          if (abbreviations.hasOwnProperty(abbreviation)) {
            if (match === abbreviations[abbreviation].abbreviation) {
              console.log("match YES!");
              console.log("match", match);
              console.log(
                "abbreviation in the object: ",
                abbreviations[abbreviation].abbreviation
              );
              return abbreviations[abbreviation].expansion; // return DOG, CAT or HORSE (if any match)
            } else {
              console.log("match - NO!");
              return "";
            }
          }
        }
        return match;
      })
      .replace(filterPattern3, " ")
      .trim() // remove leading and trailing whitespace.
      .toUpperCase(); // change string to upper case.
    console.log("ORGINAL STRING:" + testStringOriginal);
    console.log("CONVERTED STRING:" + filteredString);
```

Comment: `for/in` is for looping over standard objects that have property names (strings) as their enumerators. Don't use it with arrays (which use numeric indexes as the enumerator). Use a regular counting loop or `.forEach()` to iterate arrays.

Comment: To clarify further, for/in will loop over all the properties of the object, including all its methods in it's prototype chain. SInce arrays are objects,  it explains why for/in on an array doesn't throw an error. The result however, is that properties like the index, the slice method, the push method etc will all be included in the loop.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply I have changed to a forEach loop instead.     .replace(filterPattern2, match => {
    abbreviations.forEach(item => {
      if (item.abbreviation === match) {
        console.log(item.abbreviation);
        console.log(match);
        console.log(item.expansion);
        match = item.expansion;
        return match;
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    });
  }) But now I get CONVERTED STRING:BLABLABLALBLA UNDEFINED COOL UNDEFINED UNDEFINED UNDEFINED

Comment: At first look i can say that you better use a Map object for the abbreviations lookup. In which the keys are abbreviations and corresponding values as expansions.

Comment: @Shilly To be really clear, only enumerable properties will be looped over, not *all* properties. You won't actually loop over `.slice`, `.push`, etc. because they are configured as non-enumerable. But, you could wind up looping over other properties you didn't intend to loop over.

Comment: Did you change all your `abbreviations[abbreviation]` references to just `item`?

Comment: Right, got it, enumerable vs non-enumerable, god bless for Object.create(null) Got confused for a second about why we used to use `.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: @Shilly **Property Descriptors** can cause a property to become non-enumerable and for native objects, many properties are set this way internally. Yes, we do have to worry about inherited properties, but only ones that are enumerable. Most `Array.prototype` properties/methods are non-enumerable, but *Array-Like* objects (like node lists) will have some properties that you don't want to loop over like `item` and `length`.

Comment: Can any of you post the solution? :) I changed to a forEach, but cant figure out how I return the values that has a match in the abbreviation array and the others only return an emtpy string. Here is the updated code https://repl.it/L0dl/0

Comment: I know I do not return anything from the replace method, thats why I get undefined... BUT if I have multiple matches how should I tell the script to return the expansions if I find a match or if not return "";

Comment: When I convert your code to use a `.forEach`, I have different code than you do and get different results. See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m175dboj/).

Comment: @ScottMarcus but your code return match which is the input so the forEach function are not doing anything. With your code we get "BLABLABLALBLA C COOL D P C" but as you know C and D exist in the abbreviations array so it should return DOG for D, CAT for C and "" for P. the output should then be "BLABLABLALBLA CAT COOL DOG CAT"